# How to declare a lua_CFunction that takes a single function argument on the stack?

Tags: c, lua

I was wondering how to use to Lua C API to create a lua_CFunction that expects a single function argument on the stack?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In the book.](http://www.lua.org/pil/26.1.html)
[In the manual.](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_CFunction)

```
// lua function that expects a single number argument
int myfunction(lua_State* L)
{
    double argument = lua_tonumber(L, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You still need to make this function available to Lua scripts. Using `lua_register` is one way.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to pass a function argument to the lua_CFunction